# How to use a different Bootstrap theme in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

So i've been looking for quite some time now on how to change from the default bootstrap theme in ASP.NET MVC 5. I can change it by using a template from bootswatch and basically copy the bootstrap.css into my current bootstrap.css.

But when I try with other themes [like this one](http://keenthemes.com/free-bootstrap-templates/asentus-free-bootstrap-corporate-html-template/)

I can't seem to get this one work or the other I tried after by changing the .css & .js like i've read through different tutorials. What am I missing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can't understand what u want actually ? Whatever theme or template you are adding to your MVC project, you just need to change the CSS and JS file accordingly to get your expected style or whatever.

Comment: They have used a seperate custom css of the theme you have mentioned. means the default bootstrap css is same there and they are adding styles in new css file. The best way is to customize bootstrap download build from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ . They will give you your own choiced boostrap.css build

Comment: @SahilDhir So I uploaded the config.json from the template in the link you provided and then downloaded the bootstrap zip file. Do I then put the new bootstrap.css & bootstrap.js in my project?

Comment: did they provide you the new build??

Comment: @SahilDhir Yes the zip file had included css, fonts, js folders & config.json.

Comment: As you might know MVC 5 is already embedded with bootstrap, and if you want to use some external Layout for your project, its pretty straight forward, as we do in ASP.NET, there is the same process which we have to follow in ASP.NET MVC as well. [Take a look at this article for further details on applying Layouts in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/how-to-render-different-layout-in-asp-net-mvc) Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer or not. Few years old now. Maybe someone else will see this. I came across this question while I was looking for answers for a different problem. If you wanna change your bootstrap theme, you simply do so in the BundleConfig.cs file. Under App_Start. This is where you'll change your various script libraries. Including Bootstrap. For example:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

I changed my default theme of bootstrap.css to bootstrap-lumen.css. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start with following some tutorials. [This](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-with-asp-net-mvc-5) one looks pretty clear and should help you out.

The concept is very simple: you add the default bootstrap scripts and content files and then you add your own scripts to override some of the settings. You can modify the default files but that's not to be recommended.

Do note that the customized scripts should be referenced after the default bootstrap files in your HTML or else they won't have any effect.